# How many times do I need to do likable actions to get max affinity?

Tags: fallout-4

I noticed that all my companions liked me healing Dogmeat, so I gathered them all in Sanctuary, damaged Dogmeat and gave him stimpaks. But I ran out of stimpaks. Does anyone know how many times you must perform a "liked" action to get them to max affinity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Fallout 4 Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Affinity):

> Typically, all companions begin at an affinity value of 0. If the affinity value reaches 500, they will "admire" the Sole Survivor and often reveal new dialogue. Raising their affinity to 1000+ (max is 1100) will result in them "idolizing" the Sole Survivor, at which point the Sole Survivor are granted their companion perk.

You gain/lose this much affinity based upon four different ways a companion perceives an action:

- Liked: +15
- Loved: +35
- Disliked: -15
- Hated: -35

Most companions start at 0, meaning to reach Max affinity of 1,100 you would need to do ~73 "liked" actions (1,100/15), or ~31.5 "loved" actions (1,100/35).  Of course you can perform any combination of these actions to reach the max.

If you consider 1,000 to be the max, since reaching 1,100 has no additional benefit besides giving you some wiggle room in the event you perform an action they dislike/hate, then you would need to do ~67 liked actions (1,000/15) or ~26 loved actions (1,000/35).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i needed i knew the 0 to 1000 part but had no idea how much points an action afected that. Now its time to somehow get 50+ stimpaks on survival to en the process jajaja

Comment: +1, but, although this may be obvious, I would still note that performing actions they dislike will increase the number. Also, note that "Affinity can be also increased passively by simply having a companion follow the Sole Survivor." And also that repeating the same action quickly won't gain more affiinity without saving and loading or switching cells (fast travel or going in/outdoors).

Comment: @DCShannon _Performing actions they dislike will increase the number_ did you mean the number of times you perform a liked action?

Comment: I mean the number of times you would need to perform a liked action to get to the max. Maybe it *wasn't* obvious. If you do 67 liked actions and one hated action, you won't be at 1000 yet.

Comment: @DCShannon no it was obvious, but I was double checking to make sure you didn't mean performing Disliked actions would increase affinity.  I was slightly confused by the wording of the comment basically.

Comment: @TimmyJim Gotcha.